# MYSQL query that can group by the highest datetime from two rows that might have the same value but flip flopped

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL 5.x database that I can't change the schema, read only access:

```
SELECT * FROM table;

--------------------+------------+------------+---------
stamp               | src        | dst        | data      
--------------------+------------+------------+---------
2017-12-06 11:08:39 | 2055551234 | 2059999999 | somedata
2017-12-04 16:04:14 | 2059999999 | 2055551234 | somedata
2017-12-04 14:28:21 | 2055551234 | 2059999999 | somedata
2017-12-04 14:26:24 | 8004441111 | 2562428766 | somedata
2017-12-04 14:06:22 | 2562428766 | 8004441111 | somedata
2017-12-04 13:15:52 | 8004441111 | 2562428766 | somedata
+---------------------+------------+------------+-------
```

I need all rows that service sets of two numbers, for example 2055551234 and 2055551234, each can be SRC or DST.  I need the most recent row.

I need rows that contain both 2055551234 and 2055551234 but in either SRC or DST columns.  The values can be in either column and thus my problem.

Each of the matching SRC,DST sets has multiple rows, I need the row with the most recent datetime from each set.

I thought I had it outsmarted when I decided to try to create a hash with MD5(SRC+DST) which would also equal MD5(DST+SRC) but I got unreliable results.

There can be anywhere from 1 to thousands of groups of rows that have matching sets.

I need to be able to LIMIT the results so just iterating client side isn't going to work because of the unknown rows in each group.

I can't store any procedures, any iterating work will have to be done client side.

From the above data I would like:

```
--------------------+------------+------------+---------
stamp               | src        | dst        | data      
--------------------+------------+------------+---------
2017-12-06 11:08:39 | 2055551234 | 2059999999 | somedata
2017-12-04 14:26:24 | 8004441111 | 2562428766 | somedata
+---------------------+------------+------------+-------
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Ok I see what you want...what are you getting , and show your query pls

Comment: Please explain how your result is obtained.  For example, where did `2017-12-06 11:08:22` come from?

Comment: Yeah, if you're looking for rows that contain `2055551234` or `2059999999`, how does your second result row get selected?

Comment: You want rows that contain both values, but in either column, right?

Comment: @miknik exactly!

Comment: @PM77-1 that was just a type-o in my post, fixed.

Comment: Still not clear. You're stating that you want to select a row but your result includes non-existing rows.

Comment: I fixed the type-o, sorry about that and thanks for any help.

Comment: What data types are `src` and `dst`?

Comment: SRC and DST are varchar's but are consistently 10-digit phone numbers that never start with a 0.

Comment: @BillKervaski can you test my solution? :)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, now I think I got it. You are not looking for two particular numbers; you are looking for groups of rows that have the same number pair, no matter in what order. So get the lesser and the greater value and group.

```
select *
from mytable
where (least(src, dst), greatest(src, dst), stamp) in
(
  select least(src, dst), greatest(src, dst), max(stamp)
  from mytable
  group by least(src, dst), greatest(src, dst)
);
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bed58/1

Comment: This is looking promising! I'm comparing the data after dinner and will post back.  High hopes!

Comment: This is definitely closer than I was but if there are values for src and dst switched it treats them as seperate rows in the results.  I need each set of src,dst (regardless of their order) to be treated as one and just the most recent datetime of the set returned in the results.

Comment: I don't see how this should be possible with my query. You must have made a mistake when trying it. My query doesn't look at `src` and `dst` separately, it always looks at `least(src, dst)` and `greatest(src, dst)`. So no matter whether a record contains 123/456 or 456/123, my query treats both as 123/456, because `least` is 123 and `greatest` is 456 for both. Here is a SQL fiddle to prove this works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bed58/1.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytbl AS t1
WHERE stamp IN (
    SELECT MAX(stamp) AS maxStamp
    FROM (
        SELECT *, CONCAT(GREATEST(src, dst), '.', LEAST(src, dst)) AS gbval 
        FROM `mytbl` AS t2
    ) AS t3
    GROUP BY t3.gbval
    HAVING maxStamp = t1.stamp
)
```

Does this work?